# "Достаться на орехи" — почему негативный характер?

Tags: этимология, фразеология, значение-слов

**Достанется же мне на орехи!** — то есть накажут за что-то.
А почему вообще **на орехи** и **что** достанется?

Answer (score 2):

Орехи всегда были излюбленным лакомством детей. были доступны и стоили недорого (не грецкие, а земляные, с лещины). Часто отцы семейств, возвращавшиеся с работы, давали детям пару копеек на орехи. Если же маленькие сорванцы в отсутствие отца вели себя не как следует, то мать грозила им пальцем: «Вот отец вернется, будет вам на орехи!» и  прибавляла: «Таких калёных орехов всыпет, долго не забудете”. (Это приём иронии-обратное значение, как ,например, "Дай мороженое!-Я вот тебе дам мороженое!")Так выражение “на орехи” стало угрозой наказания – не слишком сурового, но вполне ощутимого.

Comment: "лещина" и "земляной орех" - это две большие разницы.

А вообще из этого текста не очень понятно, таки почему именно негативное.  
Я когда-то давно видел варианты выражения "досталось на калачи" и проч. Совсем уж как-то не вяжется с подобной версией.

Comment: Я в курсе, что разные, потому и через запятую. А негативное связано не с орехами, а с глаголом достанется.Иногда говорили просто"Смотри, достанется" Подразумевалось, что достанется "трёпка", а не орехи. А "орехи"- символ желаемого, но недосягаемого для шалунов удовольствия, которое заменится наказанием. Потом осталось только значение наказания, как слышат про орехи - видят угрозу.

Comment: В "Кошкином доме" котята: "Мы кошкины племя-я-янники!" Привратник Василий: "Вот я вам дам на пряники!" Значение такое же, как в случае с орехами и калачами))))

Comment: Точно!....